# Pandas dataframe has regex keywords

Tags: pandas

I have a df with list of keywords and its corresponding columns

```
   Column 1         Column2  Column3 
    Processing        Test     CPI
    WCR               Key      Comp
    DD|FF         Interp   Set ( If both keywords are present then 
                                     select this row)
```

**Folder path** : C:\WCR basic\testing\dual, it should match with column1 **WCR** row value and return value of column2 and column3. **Output : Key, Comp**

When i loop through the list of filepath, if file path contains any of the keyword present in column1 then it should retrun the values from column2 and 3. I am not sure if using regex in this situation would give better result?

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you might have an easier time using a list comprehension, and searching whether each value of `Column 1` is a substring of your folder path:

```
folder_path = 'C:\\WCR basic\\testing\\dual'

>>> df.loc[[i in folder_path for i in df['Column 1']], ['Column2','Column3']]
  Column2 Column3
1     Key    Comp
```

Comment: I want to use regular expression to handle a scenario to check 2 keywords and if both keywords are present then select the row, I used                                     
df.loc[[ any(re.findall(i, folder_path, re.IGNORECASE))  for i in df['column1']], ["column2","column3]] . in this case regex works as OR condition how to change it to AND to ensure both words are present?